# Pass boolean values as input to method

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I pass boolean as argument to a method ?

For example, I have a code as below:

```
def msg_util(self, auth_type=None,starttls=False):
....
starttls=True
invoke_tls(self, auth_type, auth_value, "require_tls=%s" %starttls)
....
....
def invoke_tls(self, auth_type=None, auth_value=None,range=None,style=None, adminuser=None,require_tls=False):
...
```

Since am passing `starttls` as string from `invoke_tls` method, in the method definition `invoke_tls`, if `require_tls` is not set to boolean False by default, `starttls` is taken as "True" (string)

Please let me know if there is a way I can pass boolean type as optional parameters in python.

I know that one way is to process the string in if else condition and process it as below:

```
def t_or_f(arg):
    ua = str(arg).upper()
    if 'TRUE'.startswith(ua):
       return True
    elif 'FALSE'.startswith(ua):
       return False
```

But, please let me know if there is any other effective or better way to pass boolean values as input to another method ?

Comment: If you don't pass it, `False` will be the default value passed.

Comment: Same way you pass any other parameter. Booleans aren't special.

Comment: Why do you make it a string?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I need to pass True

Comment: @user2357112 since the parameter is Named Python Functional Parameters (with defaults), I will need to pass the parameter name and parameter value

Comment: @ArunShankar check 6502's answer.

Comment: Thank you, but what if the value for c is coming from other method and the variable name is x? So, we will not be able to invoke foo(1, c=x). So I was using foo(1, "c=%s"%x)

Comment: @ArunShankar: Why wouldn't you be able to do `foo(1, c=x)`?

Comment: And why are you trying to pass `invoke_tls` a parameter it doesn't take? It has no `starttls` parameter.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, my bad. I changed starttls to require_tls in invoke_tls method invocation. Type issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's nothing special about `True` or `False` values...

```
invoke_tls(self, auth_type, auth_value, starttls)
```

If what you mean is how to pass specific parameters but not others, Python has "keyword parameters":

```
def foo(a, b=1, c=False):
    print(a, b, c)

foo(1)          # b will be 1 and c False (default values)
foo(1, c=True)  # b will be 1 (default) and c True
```

Python also allows to specify keyword arguments dynamically... for example

```
parms = {"c" : True}  # Dictionary name → value
foo(1, **parms)       # b will be 1 (default), c will be True
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if the value for c is coming from other method and the variable name is x? So, we will not be able to invoke `foo(1, c=x)`. So I was using `foo(1, "c=%s"%x)`

Comment: You can and should use `foo(1, c=x)`. Can't see the problem here.

Comment: @ArunShankar: if the **name** of the parameter is dynamic you can use the `**dict` syntax in the call. If the problem is just parameter value you can simply write `foo(1, c=x)`

Comment: @6502 The above solution helped, the parameter was dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Boolean is a data type and can be passed around as any other data type.

Check:

```
a = True
def foo(b=None):
    print b
foo(a)
```

Output:

```
True
```